# Tensor product with an L on top

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tensor-products, homology-cohomology

Looking at the definition of the Kunneth morphism in SGA4, XVII, 5.4.1.4, there is the notation
 $$Rf_*K \overset{\mathbb{L}}{\boxtimes}_{\mathcal{A}_0} Rg_* L \rightarrow Rh_*(K \overset{\mathbb{L}}{\boxtimes}_{\mathcal{A}_0} L).$$

Likewise, in [this entry](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/K%C3%BCnneth_formula) on the Kunneth formula in the Encyclopedia of Math, there is
 $$Rp_*(\mathcal{F})\overset{L}{\bigotimes_{\mathcal{O}_S}} Rq_*(\mathcal{G}) = Rh_*\left(\mathcal{F} \overset{L}{\bigotimes_{\mathcal{O}_S}} \mathcal{G}\right).$$

I can't seem to find a definition of this tensor, nor if $\mathbb{L}$ or $L$ is merely part of the symbol or an object in its own right.

Comment: $\overset{\mathbf{L}}{\otimes}$ is the left derived tensor product. You can think of it as a refinement of $\mathrm{Tor}_*$.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Thanks, I'd consider this an answer to the question.

Comment: It doesn't explain the first formula. _That_ is not the derived tensor product.

Comment: The first formula is presumably using the external derived tensor product.

Comment: @ZhenLin: All I needed was that the $L$ stood for "left derived".